# Sorting list with etoolbox

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox

I would like make a listing of shortseries fields in my .bib file. I see `etoolbox` can help make to made a list of themes and to loop on them. My idea is :

- for each entry, add the shortseries and series fiels to a list when the entry is cited.
- loop to this list at end

But I would like sort this list by alphabetic order. For example, my list could be :
`CCSA, BHG`, and I would like this be `BHG, CCSA`

Comment: biblatex uses biber or BibTeX to sort bibliographic data. What output are you trying to achieve? If it's a list like the list of shorthands, you could define a new bibliography environment and sorting scheme and use the new biber-only `sorting` option in `\printbibliography`.

Comment: yes, it s what I'm now doing. The problem was to write in final bibliography only series. But I found ! Will publish an article.

Comment: yes, it's working. In fact, I thought to use biber sorting this night, 5 minutes after posted this topic.

Comment: OK. The solution to the problem of listing shortseries is written in my article http://geekographie.maieul.net/Collection-sous-forme-abregee-avec